# store 300*1024*1024 in 64bit variable as low and high bit

Tags: c, 64-bit, endianness

I am trying to understand how 300*1024*1024 value will be stored in a 64bit variable on a big endian machine and how will we evaluate the high and low bytes?

Comment: depends on the "endianness" of your machine architecture.

Comment: The actual storage would probably depend upon the underlying CPU architecture...

Comment: This depends on what hardware you are using how exactly it will be stored in memory.  But `C` provides an abstraction, if you want to look at the high and low bytes just think use hex or binary constants and you will be fine.  Shifts, binary ANDs and the rest will work just fine.

Comment: 64 bit unsigned integer (uint64_t), 64 bit signed integer (int64_t) or floating point (double)?

Comment: it is for Big-endian hardware. sorry that I didn't mention in in my first post. and I need info for both signed and un-signed 64bit

Answer (score 2):

Build a union with long integer and an array of 8 unsigned chars and see for yourself.  You can view the unsigned chars in hex if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Big-endian hardware stores the most significant byte first in memory. Little-endian hardware stores the least significant byte first. In hex 300*1024*1024 is 0x12C00000.

So, for your big-endian hardware it will be stored like so:

```
byte number  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
value        00 00 00 00 12 C0 00 00
```

On LE hardware the bytes will be stored in reverse order:

```
byte number  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
value        00 00 C0 12 00 00 00 00
```